# mock unittest for input type

Tags: python, unit-testing, mockito, python-unittest

I want to do unit test for input type to check if all input are valid in the function `make_list`. `make_list` will be called in CLI api so I want to make sure that when the user input incorrectly, it will tell user what is the error. I think about `mockito.matchers` but am sure how to use it.

```py
def make_list(
    token: Token,
    l_name: str,
    d_name: Optional[str] = None,
    g_type: Optional[str] = "p",
    debug: bool = False,
) -> Optional[ClassA]:
```

Comment: What do you want to mock? If you are testing `make_list`, you can pass whatever you want as arguments. If there's a local variable *inside* the function that you can't otherwise influence, then you'll want to use a mock library.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `make_list` will be called in CLI api so I want to make sure that when the user input incorrectly, it will tell user what is the error. That's why I want to do unit test for `token, l_name, d_name, g_type`